# Native Subprocess Can't Create File in Application Folder or on SDcard

Tags: android, permissions, native, android-ndk

Since this turned out to be a long read, I'll start with a very truncated version:

Are native processes not allowed to create/edit files created by their spawning java process regardless of having appropriate location/ permission/ file ownership?

The full question:

My application consists of a set of native binaries compiled with the NDK toolchain and a typical java Android interface. The native programs are packaged in the /assets folder and copied by the java application out into a /data/data/com.domain.app/nativeApplication folder.

There are two native application in question. One which modifies a jpeg created by the java layer, and a second which analyzes that jpeg and returns an int as output. The issue is this: When called by the java layer, the jpeg modifier doesn't work.

I've done a good amount of troubleshooting on it already so I'll try to dissuade you from some of the obvious potential answers starting with the most obvious.

Correct Compilation:
Through adb shell I can call both of the programs in question, as is, from the phone's disk. The second image analyzer program runs without a hitch when called either via adb or as designed in the software IF I do the intermediary step manually from adb.

Permissions:

Jpg Permission - The application has permission to write to external storage. I've tried to have the file read in from both the SDcard and /data/data/com.domain.app/nativeApp/img/name.jpg; no joy. As stated the second program operates as designed when the image is in either location, *if* I manually run the first program through adb.

File/Folder Permissions: All of the folders in ~/nativeApplication/* have been created BY the android application itself, it is the owner and it has chmodded all of the sub-directories and files to 777.

Supporting Code:

Calling the jpg converter process:

```
NativeSetup.changePermission("/data/data/com.domain.program/nativeApp/img/img1.jpg");

try {    
            Process jpegConvert = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/data/com.domain.program/nativeApp/bin/jpegtransformer -opts /data/data/com.domain.program/nativeApp/img/img1.jpg > /data/data/com.domain.program/nativeApp/img/img2.jpg");
            jpegConvert.waitFor();          
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Call used to create the files in ~/nativeApp/*

```
private static void copyFile(String assetPath, String localPath, Context context) {

    try {
        InputStream in = context.getAssets().open(assetPath);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(localPath);
        int read;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
```

chmod call: (it works according to ls -l through adb)

```
static void changePermission(String localPath) {

    try {
        Process chmod = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/chmod 777 " +localPath);
        chmod.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
        out.close();
        in.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Permissions of the file the program can't edit and then output a changed copy:

```
~/nativeApp/img $ ls -l
-rwxrwxrwx app_89   app_89      93061 2011-07-23 18:38 img1.jpg
```

Permission of the application that can't edit the above jpg:

```
~/nativeApp/bin $ ls -l jpegtransformer
-rwxrwxrwx app_89   app_89      95268 2011-07-23 18:01 jpegtransformer
```

Permissions of folders in ~/nativeApp/
    ~/nativeApp $ ls -l
    drwxrwxrwx app_89   app_89            2011-07-23 17:57 bin
    drwxrwxrwx app_89   app_89            2011-07-23 18:27 img

Theories:

At this point my only viable theory is that there is some android policy not governed by chmod which is keeping the jpegtransformer from editing the image when called by the java layer. Since the image analyzer doesn't change the image I imagine it skirts this? Are native processes not allowed to create files? Any ideas would be great. Sorry for the long read.

-SS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is not related to permissions - you try to redirect the output using `>`, while this is a shell operator and does not work from java. grab the process output stream and write it to a file using Java standard file I/O API.

Though I'm not sure this is the problem, you shouldn't have problem to modify files in your app folder and the issue I described is an issue I met more than once.

Comment: Ahh! I almost wish it had been a more complex answer for the amount of time I wasted staring at this today. However, I'm glad to say that the **>** was the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help :). To say the truth, once I observed `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` in your question, I directly went for that. Bad experience pays at the end...

Answer (score 2):

When you spawn a process from your app, it runs under the same uid as you do, so all of the same Android and filesystem permissions apply.  I think you need to look for something else going on, such as using bad paths.

If you want to verify, just use "adb shell ps" to see the running processes and you should see that your process has the same uid as your main app.

That said...  Android really does not support spawning processes like this, and it is strongly discouraged.  Please consider doing this just by loading the native code as a shared library and using JNI to call it.  This will also be a lot more efficient, and communication with your native code potentially simpler since JNI is a much richer and more direct way to call in to it.